# Make a group of buttons fill the whole width of the parent div

Tags: html, css, button, width, navbar

I have a small panel with a width of `360px`. At the top of the panel, there is a navigation bar consisting of currently 3 buttons (the number should not matter though). I want the buttons to fill out the whole width of the div and take up more or less space depending on the length of the word inside. Currently, I only know how to set the width of the buttons to a value, but then if I add a button the values would need to be changed manually.

[image: what it currently looks like]

this is what I have now, but obviously it looks horrible. How can I make the first button less wide, the second button wider and have all three buttons together take up the whole width of the panel?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="buttons">SHORT</li>
            <li class="buttons">LOOOOOOOOOOONG</li>
            <li class="buttons">...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
.panel {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 360px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.buttons {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #666666;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go with a flexbox solution for this:

```css
.panel {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 360px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
  /* add the following */
  width:100%;
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:row;
}

.buttons {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #666666;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  
  /* remove your width and float and add the following */
  flex-grow:1;
}

/*optional*/
.nav li:last-child {border-right:none;}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="buttons a">SHORT</li>
    <li class="buttons b">LOOOOOOOOOOONG</li>
    <li class="buttons c">...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[More information about flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

[A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: This is one is highly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

It's a balance between `.buttons` `padding`, `font-size` and `width`. If you give `with: 33%;` with the current `padding (20px)` it will not work. If you set `padding: 0px;` it will but looong text will overflow, setting `font-size` lower can help but it will still be too tight.

Try tweaking those things a bit and see if you can nail the right balance.

Below example:

```css
.panel {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 360px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: -2px;
}

.buttons {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 33%;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #666666;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="buttons">SHORT</li>
        <li class="buttons">LOOOOOOOOOOONG</li>
        <li class="buttons">...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You canremove `Width` (will be set by its content) and set `display:inline-block` (instead of float) to achieve that. try this one.

```css
.panel {
background-color: grey;
width: 360px;
height: 600px;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav {
  margin:0 0;
  padding:0 0;
  width:100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    min-width:23.3%;
    margin-right: -4px;
  
    background-color: #666666;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;

}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="buttons">SHORT</li>
            <li class="buttons">LOOOOOOOOOOONG</li>
            <li class="buttons">...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: but the three buttons don't take up the full width of the outer div and they now have a gap in between each

Comment: weu, in that case flexbox is preferable by @Pete

Comment: the closest one i can get is to  give `min-width` - but not as flexible as flex. I edited answer please take a look.

Comment: better, but I would comment out the space between your elements too to remove the white space between them

Comment: got that. Playing with css is a bit tricky for me :) 
by flex we can just use `flex-grow:1` instead soo elegant

Comment: flex is the future! even everyone's favourite pile of rubbish bootstrap is moving onto flex!

Comment: what the...!!! I mentioned about you @Pete, and now just realize that I am talking with you

Thanks Pete :)

Answer (score -1):

you can apply 33.33% width and remove border and padding

```css
.panel {
background-color: grey;
width: 360px;
height: 600px;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}
.buttons {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 33.33%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.buttons.a{
  background-color: red;
}
.buttons.b{
  background-color: green;
}
.buttons.c{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="buttons a">SHORT</li>
    <li class="buttons b">LOOOOOOOOOOONG</li>
    <li class="buttons c">...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```